# Bitcoin fork having a per-block reward less than 1 coin

Tags: c++, bitcoin

Can I have Bitcoin fork that rewards less than 1.00000000 per block? I've seen the line

> LINE 831 int64 nSubsidy = 1 * COIN;

But I can't find where COIN is set. Maybe the issue is in the int64, can I get away with making that a double?

Failing that, could I remove or reduce the number of decimal places used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coin is defined here:  https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/amount.h#L16

```
static const CAmount COIN = 100000000;
```

So the amount is in satoshis.